# JAVA: datastructure like a table without using a database?

Tags: java, csv

I have a couple of files. Each file is for a month. e.g.

file-januar.csv

```
ID, From, To
1234, 2022-01-01, 2022-01-02
1235, 2022-07-01, 2022-08-20
```

file-februar.csv

```
ID, From, To
1234, 2022-01-01, 2022-01-02
1235, 2022-08-21, 2022-08-30
```

file-march.csv
...

The id is unique in each file. If the record did not change in the file for january and february is the same entry:

```
1234, 2022-01-01, 2022-01-02
```

If the record changes the entry for januar and februar are different

```
1235, 2022-07-01, 2022-08-20
1235, 2022-08-21, 2022-08-30
```

I need to create a single file without any duplicates in chronological order. My problem: I can not use a database.

Has sombody an idea howto create a single file januar-dezember without any duplicates? Each file has about 10.000 rows. How can i handle it? And how can i sort it chronological?

Comment: Store each row as a String in a Set (that will take care of duplicates), then define a Comparator that will split the row at the first and second comma, and return the order you want based on those columns (chronological and id), use it to sort your set into a List, dump the list to a new file

Comment: store whatever wanted in a custom List<YourRecord>, sort it by any criteria, then export it (csv). Could take advance also of Stream to process further (filters, etc)

Comment: Or better, use this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

Answer (score 1):

I would store each line in a `Map<Integer, String>` where the key is the unique ID (I suppose it is a number, but you also could use a string) and the value is the complete line.

Then read in each file in chronological order and store it into the map. Entries from later files will overwrite entries from earlier ones.

In the end you can write out the Map like this:

```
Set<Integer> keys = allValuesMap.keySet();
List<Integer> keyList = new ArrayList<>(keys);
Collections.sort(keyList);
for (Integer key: keyList) {
  System.out.println(allValuesMap.get(key));
}
```

(Of course you would probably replace the `System.out` with another file.)

If that doesn't work, you could try to use an in-memory database like [H2](https://h2database.com).